# Dump Pandas Dataframe to multiple json files

Tags: json, pandas

I have a Dataframe loaded from a CSV file

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header=0)
```

and I want to process it and eventually save it into multiple JSON files (for example a new file every X rows).

Any suggestion how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
for idx, group in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//10): 
    group.to_json(f'{idx}_name.json', orient='index') # orient: split, records, index, values, table, columns
```

Change the `10` to the number of rows you wish to write out for each iteration.

Comment: Also, `import numpy as np` :)

Comment: Thanks  for your help, approach makes sense but I get an error
`'dict' object has no attribute 'to_json'`

Comment: Sorry about that - fixed

Comment: Edit: made more succinct with the `orient` kwarg.